# Where can I find classification of Indian food items based on its guna?

Tags: scripture, food, reference-request, gunas, ayurveda

There are three Gunas: Sattva, Rajas, Tamas. Based on the occupation and some other aspects, people take particular types of foods.

Scriptures generally encourage the intake of Sattvic food since it leads humans towards knowledge and peace.

If we search online, there may be many opinions on whether a particular food is sattvic or rajasic or tamasic.

In this context, I want to know whether there is any scripture or *list* (from scriptures) that contains an exhaustive list of foods and their corresponding guna.

Are there any resources available to check whether food falls into a particular guna?

Comment: Short answer - No. Why ? Whether food is sattvik , rajas or tamas for you depends on your body type - vata, pitah or kapha. Unless you first figure out your body type you can't talk about Guna of a given food.

Comment: @Carmensandiego I'm asking for general categorization.

Comment: As what is considered food can vary over time and place, a complete list is futile. Krishna gives the advice as to how to classify the gunas of food in Gita 17.8-10.

Comment: That's what I am saying @hanugm. There is no general categorization

Comment: @Carmensandiego I don't think that guna of a food is just a function of time and place. The nature of food do matter.

Comment: Time and place ? I am saying it depends on your body type

Comment: @Carmensandiego is there any reference for the same?

Comment: Think i read it in charak samitha. Will post it once I find it again

Comment: hangum generally foods which are extremely spicy or contains too much chillies are rajasic,